# JTable Mouse Listener Mouse Adapter

Tags: java, swing, jtable, mouselistener

i am making a point of sale system and i have two tables here, tableOne and tableTwo.
what i want to do is click a row in tableOne and it will appear in tableTwo

but i have an error on my console

```
"java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4 >= 4"
```

my code works fine, when that error shows on my console i just continue clicking the rows and it works. How can i remove the error?

```
// row,col is the row and column in tableOne ( Where we will get the data )
// trow,trow is the row and column in tableTwo  ( Where we will put the data )

public void tebel(){
    table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
            if(e.getClickCount() == 2) {

                target = (JTable)e.getSource();
                int row = target.getSelectedRow();
                int col= 0;
                int trow = 0;
                int tcol = 0;
                if(row>=0){
                    while(tcol<=tableOne.getColumnCount()){
                        tableTwo.setValueAt(tableOne.getValueAt(row,col),trow,tcol);
                        col++;
                        tcol++;
                        if(tcol==tableOne.getColumnCount()){
                            trow++;
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 2) Words typed in all lower case are hard to read, like trying to listen to someone who is mumbling.  Please use an upper case letter at the start of sentences, for the word I, and proper names like `ArrayList` or Oracle.

Comment: Use a [`ListSelectionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while(tcol<=tableOne.getColumnCount()){
```

I would guess your condition should be `<`

Comment: hi thanks for the answer. is Listselectionlistener much preferable compared to my code? Or my code is also fine?

Comment: @proton32 A ListSelectionListener would be used if the logic was based on a single mouse click. The listener is invoked when you click on a row or use the arrow keys to move to a new row. Since you are listening for a double click, the MouseListener is the way to go. However you may also want to add support to handle the "Enter" key to process the row. Check out [List Action](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/14/list-action/). The code provided there is for a JList, but the concept is the same and it should just be a matter of changing the class to use a JTable instead of a JList.